# Exporting a model from R's caret, for use elsewhere

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I've built a successful diagnostic tool using caret in R; it's a complex ensemble of random forests, xgbtree, neural networks etc. I want to write javascript code that will allow a user to input patient data and get a diagnostic result. But how can I get the complex caret model out of R, for use in other environments?

Any ideas on how to make this happen, or where to start?

Comment: Check the PMML package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmml/index.html

Comment: Look into using OpenCPU (https://www.opencpu.org/) or Plumber (https://github.com/rstudio/plumber). Here's an example for deploying an ML model using the Plumber web API approach: https://www.shirin-glander.de/2018/01/plumber/